# How can I assign user input (words) an integer value to be used in the code

Tags: java, parsing, random, java.util.scanner

I'm attempting to create a game of "Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock", and want the user to be able to put in either the integers assigned to the variables `(Rock=0, Paper=1, Scissors=2, Lizard=3 and Spock=4)` and also be able to enter the words `"Rock", "Paper", "Scissors", "Lizard"` or `"Spock"`. Could you help me include a part of the code where I can assign the string inputs to integers. I also do not want to change the main framework of the code. I also know that the website says not to paste the entire file, but I cannot think of another way to show my problem. Please note that I have been using a website called [SoloLearn](https://code.sololearn.com/#java). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RockPaperScissorsLizardSpock {

    final static int ROCK = 0;
    final static int PAPER = 1;
    final static int SCISSORS = 2;
    final static int LIZARD = 3;
    final static int SPOCK = 4;


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double r = Math.random();
        int computerChoice = (int)(3.0 * r);

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter 0 for Rock, 1 for Paper, 2 for Scissors, 3 for Lizard, 4 for Spock: ");
        int playerChoice = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println(computerChoice);

    int playerChoice = 0;

    switch (playerChoice) {

        case "Rock":
            playerChoice = 0;
            break;
        case "Paper":
            playerChoice = 1;
            break;
        case "Scissors":
            playerChoice = 2;
        case "Lizard":
            playerChoice = 3;
        case "Spock":
            playerChoice = 4;

    if (computerChoice == playerChoice) {
            System.out.println("Tie");
        }
        else if (computerChoice == ROCK && playerChoice == SCISSORS) {
            System.out.println("I chose Rock,You chose Scissors, Rock crushes Scissors, You lose.");
        }
        else if (computerChoice == SCISSORS && playerChoice == PAPER) {
            System.out.println("I chose Scissors, You chose Paper, Scissors cut Paper, You lose.");
        }
        else if (computerChoice == PAPER && playerChoice == ROCK) {
            System.out.println("I chose Paper,You chose Rock, Paper covers Rock, You lose.");
        }
         else if (computerChoice == LIZARD && playerChoice == PAPER) {
            System.out.println("I chose Lizard, You chose Paper, Lizard eats Paper, You lose.");
        }
        else if (computerChoice == SPOCK && playerChoice == SCISSORS) {
            System.out.println("I chose Spock, You chose Scissors, Spock smashes Scissors, You lose.");
        }
        else if (computerChoice == ROCK && playerChoice == LIZARD) {
            System.out.println("I chose Rock, You chose Lizard, Rock crushes Lizard, You lose.");
        }
        else if (computerChoice == SCISSORS && playerChoice == LIZARD) {
            System.out.println("I chose Scissors, You chose Lizard, Scissors decapitates Lizard, You lose.");
        }
        else if (computerChoice == SPOCK && playerChoice == PAPER) {
            System.out.println("I chose Spock, You chose Paper, Paper disproves Spock, You lose.");
        }
        else if (computerChoice == SPOCK && playerChoice == ROCK) {
            System.out.println("I chose Spock, You chose Rock, Spock vaporizes Rock, You lose.");
        }
        else if (computerChoice == SCISSORS && playerChoice == ROCK) {
            System.out.println("I chose Scissors, You chose Rock, Rock crushes Scissors, You win.");
        }
        else if (computerChoice == PAPER && playerChoice == SCISSORS) {
            System.out.println("I chose Paper, You chose Scissors, Scissors cut Paper, You win.");
        }
        else if (computerChoice == ROCK && playerChoice == PAPER) {
            System.out.println("I chose Rock, You chose Paper, Paper covers Rock,You win.");
        }
        else if (computerChoice == PAPER && playerChoice == LIZARD) {
            System.out.println("I chose Paper, You chose Lizard, Lizard eats Paper, You win.");
        }
        else if (computerChoice == SCISSORS && playerChoice == SPOCK) {
            System.out.println("I chose Scissors, You chose Spock, Spock smashes Scissors, You win.");
        }
         else if (computerChoice == LIZARD && playerChoice == ROCK) {
            System.out.println("I chose Lizard, You chose Rock, Rock crushes Lizard, You win.");
        }
        else if (computerChoice == LIZARD && playerChoice == SCISSORS) {
            System.out.println("I chose Lizard, You chose Scissors, Scissors decapitates Lizard,  win.");
        }
        else if (computerChoice == PAPER && playerChoice == SPOCK) {
            System.out.println("I chose Paper, You chose Spock, Paper disproves Spock, You win.");
        }
        else if (computerChoice == ROCK && playerChoice == SPOCK) {
            System.out.println("I chose Rock, You chose Spock, Spock vaporizes Rock, You win.");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: int playerChoice = input.nextInt(); -> this reads an int. to read a word: String word = input.next();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that your user can input 2 Values for 1 condition you can convert the value from **playerChoice** to String for a temp String and then make a switch case for it like the following:

```
 String tempString = Integer.toString(playerChoice);


        switch (tempString) {
        case "0":
        case "Rock":
            playerChoice = 0;
            break;
        case "1":
        case "Paper":
            playerChoice = 1;
            break;
        case "2":
        case "Scissors":
            playerChoice = 2;
            break;
        case "3":
        case "Lizard":
            playerChoice = 3;
            break;
        case "4":
        case "Spock":
            playerChoice = 4;
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but whereabouts in the code should I put this, and what should I delete?

Comment: use instead of your switch case block mine and 
 and delete **int playersChoice = 0;**  
it might give you an error.... because you already created it before. 
In Java you cannot create a **Variable** with the same name twice.
But you can create **methods** with the **same name** but **different parameters**.

Answer (score 0):

You could put your allowed inputs in a `map`, `key` being the text and `value` being the associated number:

```
private static final Map<String, Integer> ALLOWED_INPUTS = Collections.unmodifiableMap(Map.of(
    "ROCK", 0,
    "PAPER", 1,
    "SCISSORS", 2,
    "LIZARD", 3,
    "SPOCK", 4
));
```

Then, in your main function, check if the `map` contains a `key` that corresponds to the user input, if so get the corresponding `value`. If not, check if the user entered a number. Keep looping while the resulting number either way isn't in the `map`'s values.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int playerChoice = -1;
String input;

while(!ALLOWED_INPUTS.containsValue(playerChoice)) {
    input = in.nextLine();
    if (ALLOWED_INPUTS.containsKey(input))
        playerChoice = ALLOWED_INPUTS.get(input);
    else {
        try {
            playerChoice = Integer.parseInt(input);
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {}
    }
}

System.out.println("You choosed choice number " + playerChoice);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming : Either Words or Integers are entered as inputs.

Steps for this solution:

1. Always Entering String Input: **String choice = input.next();**
2. Checking if choice contains only digits, if yes,convert this to Integer else don't do anything.
3. if entered input is words, it will go to switch first,then set playerChoice and run properly.
4. if entered input is digit, it will assign converted integer to playerChoice first, then it will go to switch but as no default exists, it will run properly.

```java
        String choice = input.next();
        if (choice.matches("\\d+"))
            playerChoice = Integer.parseInt(choice);

        switch (choice.toUpperCase()) {
        case "ROCK":
            playerChoice = 0;
            break;
        case "PAPER":
            playerChoice = 1;
            break;
        case "SCISSORS":
            playerChoice = 2;
            break;
        case "LIZARD":
            playerChoice = 3;
            break;
        case "SPOCK":
            playerChoice = 4;
            break;

        }
```